# Css not correct for ipad/mobile

Tags: css, ipad

Recently I've created a website for a local music school. A good experience which has told me I must improve in everything and practice a lot.
[Here's the link](http://studioandco.altervista.org/petersday)

At first i thought to make it responsive, but I've soon realized I didn't have enough time and knowledges. 
Anyway for the first time I've used Html 5 and relative measures: desktop navigation seems to be ok.

There's something wrong If I make IPad and mobile tests: an empty space on the right of pages; header,content and footer don't fit the entire space, though I've set width: 100% for both of them. 
The same appears in landscape tests with Kindle Fire and Opera Mobile.

How could I fix that? I don't want to make it completely responsive, just to make the container fit all the device layout.

Comment: your HTML source is totally wired.

Comment: Hi Akhill! Do you mean it's not protected? It's not what I was asking about, but thanx anyway for your advise!

Comment: The link for the question is dead.

Answer (score 0):

For make 100% on ipad and mobile you need two things : 
• activate viewport with META (not really necessary i think for just 100% but, just try)
For example :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

• After you have a problem for display 100% you're content.
For example, you're content has width 100%, ok but you're navigation, slider and aside are width with XXEM.

For display 100% width on ipad/mobile etc.. you need add new css for that.
Example :

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
nav[role="navigation"] {width: 100%;}
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
nav[role="navigation"] {width: 100%;}
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
nav[role="navigation"] {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Hi ArtSx, thanx for your answer! If I add meta tag you've mentioned and                                                        [code]@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
#content, #bottom, #header,nav[role="navigation"] {width: 100%;}
}[/code]                                                           in css shouldn't I fix at least the empty portion on the right of the page?